# Can use ASP to call PHP soap?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, asp-classic

My customer has a PHP web service, that they want me to use.
It's PHP-based, while my *web* is ASP-based.

The ASP code looks like this:

```
Dim soapclient

WSDL_URL = "http://xxx.xxxx.xx/index.php?Action=service"

set soapclient = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")

soapclient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
```

on error resume next

> soapclient.mssoapinit WSDL_URL   ' error here

Is ASP able to call a PHP-based soap service?

or

What should I adjust?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find a way to solve this question is not use "MSSOAP.SoapClient30" to ask web service, but "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0".

Sample code like this:

url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx/xxx.php"

SoapRequest="<?xml version="&CHR(34)&"1.0"&CHR(34)&" encoding="&CHR(34)&"utf-8"&CHR(34)&"?>"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="&CHR(34)&"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&CHR(34)&" xmlns:xsd="&CHR(34)&"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&CHR(34)&" xmlns:soap="&CHR(34)&"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&CHR(34)&"><soap:Body><getList></getList></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

Set xmlhttp = server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")

xmlhttp.Open "POST",url,false

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8"

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length",LEN(SoapRequest)

xmlhttp.Send(SoapRequest)

Response.Write xmlhttp.responseText

Set xmlhttp = Nothing

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of web services and SOAP is that it *does not matter* what language the service is implemented in and on what hardware and OS it runs.

Either there is a bug in the web service or (more likely) you're calling it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ASP, I know PHP but you should have no problem accessing PHP web services from any other language, simply because the communication format is XML. Both applications would communicate using a third, intermediary language: XML. All should be fine.

Comment: XML is ok. But call is like
$ret = $client->__soapCall("getList",array());

ASP 
soapclient.mssoapinit WSDL_URL, "getList"
will error

Comment: I don't understand. Which language provides the web-service server and which the web-service client?

Comment: @March, if PHP is the provider, then you must use its SoapServer class, not SoapClient class. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php

Comment: He's writing the client, not the server.

Comment: @Michael, but just above he pasted some PHP code which involves a SoapClient. I assume he's doing some tests and doesn't have the knowledge about the PHP API.

Comment: @Michael, $ret = $client->__soapCall("getList",array()); is PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should remove the 'on error resume next' so you can see (and post) the error you're getting.